# Lowest career WAR for a 2-time+ all-star?

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

Of all MLB players who have made the all-star team at least *twice*, who has the lowest career WAR?

Is there a way to answer this question with baseball-reference or mlb savant? Or do you have to write some SQL?

Comment: Certainly possible with Stathead (baseball reference stats search), but requires an account nowadays to get useful results (they hide the first 10).  One batter has *negative* WAR who fits your criteria, amusingly (but they hide the result, so don't know who it is).

Answer (score 2):

**Worst hitters with at least two All-Star appearances**

| Rk | Player | AS | Career WAR | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hal Smith | 2 | 1.9 | 1956 | 1965 |
| 2 | Hal Wagner | 2 | 2.5 | 1937 | 1949 |
| 3 | Dave Ferriss | 2 | 2.9 | 1945 | 1950 |
| 4 | Blue Moon Odom | 2 | 3.2 | 1964 | 1976 |
| 5 | Jim Finigan | 2 | 3.4 | 1954 | 1959 |
| 6 | Harvey Haddix | 3 | 3.4 | 1952 | 1965 |
| 7 | Birdie Tebbetts | 4 | 3.7 | 1936 | 1952 |
| 8 | Rollie Hemsley | 5 | 3.8 | 1928 | 1947 |
| 9 | Don Mueller | 2 | 4.2 | 1948 | 1959 |
| 10 | Leo Durocher | 3 | 4.3 | 1925 | 1945 |

Full list at: https://stathead.com/tiny/T6CHr

I'm assuming you don't want the pitcher's WAR for hitting included in this list. I excluded pitchers from the batting war by setting a requirement of 15% in any non-pitching position. Blue Moon Odom (a pitcher) still sneaks into this list, because he was frequently used a pinch runner. I didn't want to filter out any other legit hitters who were used as a pinch runner in their career.

**Worst pitchers with at least two All-Star appearances**

| Rk | Player | Career WAR | IP | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gregory Soto | 1.9 | 254.1 | 2019 | 2023 |
| 2 | Blue Moon Odom | 2.2 | 1509 | 1964 | 1976 |
| 3 | Luis Arroyo | 3.3 | 531.1 | 1955 | 1963 |
| 4 | Mike Williams | 3.6 | 768.1 | 1992 | 2003 |
| 5 | Kazuhiro Sasaki | 3.7 | 223.1 | 2000 | 2003 |
| 6 | Joel Hanrahan | 4.3 | 404.2 | 2007 | 2013 |
| 7 | Chris Pérez | 4.7 | 379.1 | 2008 | 2014 |
| 8 | David Bednar | 5.2 | 183.2 | 2019 | 2023 |
| 9 | Al Javery | 5.6 | 1142.2 | 1940 | 1946 |
| 10 | Ryne Duren | 5.7 | 589.1 | 1954 | 1965 |

I don't know why stathead is not including the All-Star appearance in their final table.

For the pitchers, I had to set a minimum innings pitched of 150 innings. Otherwise, you'd get guys like Jose Canseco in there who pitched a couple innnigs. Why 150 innings? There's a Yankee outfielder, Ben Chapman, who was a 3x All-Star in the 1930s. In his career he pitched 141 innings.

Full list at: https://stathead.com/tiny/jwARF

Comment: Cool list. Harvey Haddix from the first list is also a pitcher who did a lot of PR. Rollie Hemsley and Leo Durocher were even all stars in years where they had negative war.